# Computing Rotation Speed In C++

Tags: c++, performance, rotation

Basically, In C++, how do I compute how long will it take for a car wheel to rotate 360 degrees while moving at a speed of 10 MPH? I've tried googling but nothing showed up. Any ideas?

As usual, I've searched this site for an answer but nothing showed up - unless I missed one.

Thanks.

Comment: `double rotation_speed = rotation_count / time_duration;`?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Pig: You might want to multiply by `2*PI` or `360.0`, depending on the angular system ;)

Comment: Sorry, I should of explained it better. For example, how long will it take for a car wheel to rotate 360 degrees while moving at a speed of 10 MPH?

Comment: @Hyper: Depends on how big the wheel is.

Comment: @Hyper: It depends on the wheel dimension. Suppose the radius of the wheel is 10 inches. The circumference of the wheel is then 2 * 10 * PI. Calculate how long it takes for a car, driving 10 MPH, to travel this distance. There's your answer...

Comment: Simple enough. Thanks, Jorgen and everybody else who contributed.

Comment: @Hyper-DarkStar `double time_duration_in_hours = circumference_in_miles / 10;`

Comment: This isn't a C++ question, it's a math question. Also, when you have to clarify a question to make it answerable, you should edit the question itself, so that others don't have to wade through the comments to find out what's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the speed of your object and the radius of the circle it moves on, then the time needed for one rotation is

```
rotation_time = 2*pi*radius/speed
```

The number of rotations per time unit is

```
rotation_speed = 1/rotation_time
```

The angular speed is

```
angular_speed = full_circle/rotation_time,
```

with the value of `full_circle` depending on your angular unit, e.g. 360 or 2*pi.